# Turn off mail notifications when in mail (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: email, macos, notifications

Does anyone know of a way to have mail notifications turned off when I'm in my mail client (more specifically, when the Message Viewer Window has focus)?
It's rather superfluous to receive a notifications in the top right when I can see the mail coming in in Mail's main window.

Answer (score 5):

Go to System Preferences > Notifications and set Mail Alert Style to "none" and also uncheck notification center, badge app icon and sound options.
This would turn off all the notifications for the default mail client.